# Inserting probe in Circuit diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

This is what I have so far, but I want to put a probe in the circuit (the green thing in the second picture).

Have any idea ?

I can't seem to find anything in circuitikz documentation, maybe I missed something.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}

    (opamp.-)   to [R,l_= ?   ?  <\ohm>](-4,0.5)
                (-4,0) to[C,l=2.2<\micro\farad>,*-](-6,0)
                to [R,l_= ?   ? <\ohm>](-8,0)
                to [sV,l_=1<\volt_{ac}>](-8,-2)                     node[ground]{}
    (opamp.+)   to [C,l=1<\micro\farad>](-4,-0.5)
                to[short](-4,0.5)

    (opamp.+)    to[R,*-,l= ?   ? <\ohm>]++(0,-2)           node[ground]{}
    (opamp.-) to ++(0,1) coordinate (leftR) -- (leftR -| opamp.out)
    to[short] (opamp.out)

    ;
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image: firstCircuit]

[image: secondCircuit]

And a little help with the spacing of the left (Resistor Capacitor) line would be appreciated, Ii's like every time i change point-to-point value everything move akwardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you liked something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
every pin/.style = {pin distance=7mm, inner sep=1pt, text=teal,
                    pin edge={teal, line width=2pt, shorten <=-2pt, 
                              {Triangle Cap[]}-{Circle[open,line width=1pt,length=1.6mm]}}
                    },
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    ( 0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.-)   to [R,l_=70 <\ohm>]             (-4,0.5)
    (-4,0) node[pin=below left:Y] {}
                to [C,l_=2.2<\micro\farad>,*-]  (-6,0) 
                to [R,l_=70 <\ohm>]             (-8,0) -- 
    (-9,0)      to [sV,l_=1<\volt_{ac}>] (-9,-2)    node[ground]{}
    (opamp.+)   to [C,l=1<\micro\farad>] (-4,-0.5)
                to [short]               (-4,0.5)
    (opamp.+)   to [R,*-,l=2143 <\ohm>] ++(0,-2)    node[ground]{}
    (opamp.-)   to [short,*-] ++(0,1) -| (opamp.out)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that will do. Thks. I didn't think about arrow or pin. Thks for the enlightment.

Comment: Thks for the layout too. I was so tired I didn't think about using a line to stretch things out. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @SebastienComtois, you are welcome! To may circuits drawing and happy TeX-ing!

Comment: ,do you happen to have a trick for Multiple Labeling? I tried a couple of thing but couldn't make it work. I would like to incorporate something like $R_s$ above or below 70\ohm. Any idea ?

Comment: A...nevermind, I found it .